# jquery autocomplete simple json array not filtered

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Doing jquery autocomplete in the most simple manner, but the results don't get filtered.

html :

```
<li>
  <div id="vo">
  <input type="text" name="motcle" class="autoMotsCle" value="">
  </div>
</li>
```

jquery :

```
$(".autoMotsCle").autocomplete({
source: "motsclef.json"
});
```

motsclef.json is formated like this :

```
[
"Arras",
"Bourgogne",
"Brouille",
"Bruges",
"Bruxelles",
"évêque",
"œuvres de loi"
]
```

Firefox Inspector shows that the term that is sent to the json file is correct :
motsclef.json?term=tes

params term = tes 
but response is the entire json array (1403 responses which is the entirety of the list).

As motsclef.json is formated like this, it didn't seem to me that I would need to do $.getJSON or $.ajax. I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote), it will always retrieve all the options because the example shown in page, filters the options in the backend and just retrieves the ones matching the term.

For doing what you want, you could probably do something like:

```
jQuery.getJSON("motsclef.json", function(data){
  $(".autoMotsCle").autocomplete({
    source: data
  });
});
```